# No associated item named `connect` found for type `openssl::ssl::SslStream<_>

Tags: rust

I'm using OpenSSL in my Rust application:

```
let mut abc = ssl::SslStream::connect(&sctx, tcp_conn).unwrap();
```

throws an exception:

```
error: no associated item named `connect` found for type `openssl::ssl::SslStream<_>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:19
  |
7 |     let mut abc = ssl::SslStream::connect(&sctx, tcp_conn).unwrap();
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have imported everything:

```
extern crate openssl;

use std::net::TcpStream;
use openssl::ssl;
```

This previously worked and the function `connect` existed.

Comment: *This previously worked and the function `connect` existed* And **what changed** between when it worked and when it didn't? Computers are not magic; things happen for a reason! What version of openssl are you using? 0.9.8 only lists two structs with `connect`, `SslConnector` and `Ssl`. An `SslStream` is the **result** of connecting.

Comment: @Shepmaster, latest.